# Public Overrides Property Text As String vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text, user-controls

I am creating a component and need to use the text property ... I can not make it work.

Visual Studio 2015

```
Public Overrides Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return TextBox1.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        TextBox1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

---> No error, but not visible

```
Public Property TText() As String
    Get
        Return TextBox1.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        TextBox1.Text = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

----> Working... but i need TEXT

Thks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6484087/17034

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text of UserControl dissappears in designer after compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483984/text-of-usercontrol-dissappears-in-designer-after-compilation)

Answer (score 2):

Solved! I need to add these attributes to get it to show up in Visual Studio:

```
<ComponentModel.Browsable(True)>  
<ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility(ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
<ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
<ComponentModel.Bindable(True)>
Public Overrides Property Text As String
    Get
        Return TextBox1.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        TextBox1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: All you really need were browsable and editorbrowsable.